# How to pass a string from one method to another method in Java

Tags: java, android

I declared string:

```
private String name;
```

1st method:

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
}
```

I want to use the value of name in this method:

```
private void setRealmData() {}
```

Comment: If both methods are in the same class they could just call the data member. Can you clarify what exactly the problem is, please?

Comment: `private void setRealmData(String stringtobereceived) {}` and then `setRealmData(name);' in 1st function

Comment: Yes both function are in same class.I want to use string name in 2nd function ie:setRealmData()

Comment: @Mike T Thanks Mike for your answer.but is there any other way without passing parameters in setRealmData

Comment: `private void setRealmData() { System.out.println(name); }` ?

Comment: name, assuming that it's declared as a class variable would be available.

Comment: @Arjan it returns null value fo string name

Comment: Then the method `collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);` returns null?

Comment: @KevinWallis method collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME); returns a string

Comment: Well you'll need to call the method `showJSON(...)` that assigns a value to `name` before the `setRealmData()` method of course.  Anyway,   I think your question is "How to use instance variables in methods in Java?" rather than "How to pass a string from one function to another function in java"?

Comment: @Arjan yes i am calling showJson before setRealmData.

Comment: Is there any other setting of the `name` variable?

Comment: Only with this code and task description it is really difficult to figure out what your problem is

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your time

Comment: Mike answer ->private void setRealmData(String stringtobereceived) {} and then `setRealmData(name);' in 1st function helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but there are two distinct cases of how to implement this:

**A. The `name` variable is an instance variable:**

```
public class myClass{
    private String name;
    private void showJSON(String response){
        // name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME); - this was your code
        this.name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME); // Set the 'name' variable to the value you want for this instance
        setRealmData();                                     // No argument passed, provided that 'name' is an instance variable
    }
    private void setRealmData(){
        System.out.println(this.name);  // Sample code
    }
}
```

**B. The `name` variable is a local variable:**

```
public class myClass{       
    private void showJSON(String response){
        String name;
        // name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME); - this was your code
        name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);  // Set the 'name' variable to the value you want for the method
        setRealmData(name);                             // Single argument passed, provided that 'name' is a local variable
    }
    private void setRealmData(string name){
        System.out.println(name);   // Sample code
    }
}
```

Note that the `myClass` class is a dummy class I used to show the scope of the variables and methods, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Except that declaring `private String name;` in a method will not compile... the question was somewhat unclear indeed.

Comment: @Arjan you are right, I just fixed it. Copy-paste is gonna be my undoing!